# Queryset taking too much time

Tags: python, django, pandas, dictionary, django-queryset

I have too calculate some values for 3000 items from database. On selecting item from selectbox, fields should be filled by jquery.

I am iterating each item, sending it into an dictionary (item name as key and tuple of variables as value) and passing this dictionary to django template.

I am sending auto_dict dictionary in template. Every time user select value from select box, on `change` function, I iterate the dictionary and get the values.
Page is taking too much time to load.

```
    class Sales(models.Model): # sales detail of items
        item_id = models.ForeignKey('Item', models.DO_NOTHING)
        # some more fields


    class Item(models.Model): # detail of items, around 3000 items
        name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
        # some more fields


    class Order(models.Model): # order detail of each order
        order_number = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
        created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True, default='NP')
        final_approval = models.CharField(max_length=3,default='No')
        order_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, choices=ORDER_TYPE)
        # some more fields


    class Orderitems(models.Model): # item detail for all order
        qty = models.IntegerField()
        item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        sales_id = models.ForeignKey(Sales, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        # some more fields
```

## -------- Edited Part ---------

I want sum of all (difference between date created and today).

```
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am using this:

```
current_date = datetime.date.today()

time_diff = OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(days=Sum((F('prev_order_items__order_id__created_at')-current_date)))
```

but this giving answer like this 181715600.0. I want something like this:

1st order - 01/07/2019, diff= 4 days * 2(quantity)

2nd order - 03/07/2019, diff - 2 days * 3(quantity)

Sum = 14

I have not add multiplying part of product in query yet.

This is for each item.

Comment: why dont you do it sql query itself? you can write a raw_query and get formatted result instead on calculating it later

Comment: Sorry I am new to django. Can you please show how can I do this.

Comment: Without studying your code very closely it's hard to know. But I can suggest a few things. First, try and count database hits. It seems that, rather than looping over items and adding a new filter on each loop, you should be [annotating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) the query outside of the loop with all the information you need on each row all provided with one database hit. You may find the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) very useful as it reports database hits.

Comment: @BerndWechner, Thanks. annotation reduced DB hits from 6797 to 7 and loading time 9 sec to .007 sec

Comment: You're welcome. Just remember QuerySets are lazy and to keep an eye on when they are evaluated. Every evaluation hits the database. So they are best built piece by piece while conserving their laziness (meaning they only record the means of getting the objects they don't fetch the objects until the objects themselves are needed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do some of the operations in single query. For example:

Lets say you have [**`related_names`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) defined like this:

```
class OrderOrderitemsTable(...):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='prev_order_items')

class OrderItemSales(...):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='sales_order_items')
```

Then you can run the query like this using [**`aggregation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(
    prev_sum_order=Sum('item__prev_order_items__qty')
).annotate(
    sale_sum_order=Sum('item__sale_order_items__qty')
).annotate(
    rating=F('sale_sum_order')/F('sale_sum_order')
).annotate(
    in_wirehouse = Sum('item__qty_in_ferma_warehouse')
)
.values(
    'prev_sum_order',
    'sale_sum_order',
    'rating',
    'in_wirehouse'
)
```

Comment: This solution worked and annotation reduced DB hits from 6797 to 7. Only we have to use annotate( prev_sum_order=Sum('prev_order_items__qty')) instead of annotate( prev_sum_order=Sum('item__prev_order_items__qty'))

Comment: Also, using all annotate in one query giving unexpected results. Use two annotate queries for two different variable. it's not increasing DB hits.